# Windows Shell Script to load csv into variables

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I am trying to use Windows built-in shell script to load this file:

```
hostname1,host_specific_file1
hostname2,host_specific_file2
hostname3,host_specific_file3
.
.
.
```

Like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=," %%i in (host-info.txt) do set clientName=%%i; set fileLoc=%%j
```

Which doesn't work but I want it to go like this:

```
:loop
For each line, Set the current_hostname=hostnamex and Set the current_file=host_specific_filex
And THEN
DO STUFF
Goto next line, Goto loop
```

Is there a method for doing this? I can't get my script wrapped around the "Goto next line" or "Handle one line at a time" concept.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Have you considered using Powershell? There's a good Import-Csv command, and a nice For-Each-Object command that is meant for looping like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can;

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=," %%i in (host-info.txt) do (
    set clientName=%%i
    set fileLoc=%%j
    call:handler
)
goto:eof

:handler
    echo client name is !clientName! location is !fileLoc!
goto:eof
```

Or Using %n notation;

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=," %%i in (host-info.txt) do call:handler %%i %%j
goto:eof

:handler
    echo client name is %1 location is %2 ...
```